# DNX start multiple websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I have a folder A, which including two websites project. Can I start them only one command?

Such as `dnx <something here> kestrel`. For now, I have to switch to each website root directory, and execute command `dnx . kestrel` separately.

Any suggestion is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `.` in the command is saying "start the site in this folder". Alternatively, you should be able to provide a path to a folder. Example: `dnx Project1 kestrel` if you're in the directory above the project, and the project is in a folder called "Project1".

Knowing that, you can then build a batch file to launch both from one command. Put these commands in a separate file, probably in the directory above the projects. You may need to replace Project1 and Project2 with the correct absolute or relative paths to the folders the projects are in.

```
dnx Project1 kestrel
dnx Project2 kestrel
```

---

### Windows

If you're on Windows, then you would probably use `.cmd` for the file extension. Then you can launch the file from the command prompt by entering the name of the file, ex, `LaunchBothSites.cmd`. Or you can double click the file in Windows Explorer.

---

### Linux

If you're on Linux, you typically give the file a `.sh` extension. You may also need to mark the file as executable. For example, `chmod +x LaunchBothSites.sh`. Then you can launch the site from the command line with `./LaunchBothSites.sh`.